# How to update a content or row of data values in a csv file with PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, export-to-csv

I need to update a `.csv` file without adding any extra row or new line, so I need just update a single row data. Input data is form of row and I'm using `foreach` loop.

Please help to guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd step use `ForEach` and go through each row, change the one that needs to be changed, and then make a new output file.

Imagine a `.csv` like this

`Animal,Name,Age
Cat,Finnegan,3
Cat,Pippin,5
Dog,Fido,2
Lizard,Draco,1`

Suppose I wanted to change the Animal type from lizard to Cat.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\Path\To\Your.csv
$outputFile = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach($row in $csv){
    If ("Lizard" -eq $row.Animal){
        Write-Output "Changing Animal type for $($row.Name) from $($row.Animal) to 'Cat'"
        $row.Animal = 'Cat'
    }
    $outputFile.Add($row) | Out-Null
}

$outputFile | Export-Csv c:\Path\To\Updated.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This would give an output of this for any rows that change:

```
Changing Animal type for Draco from Lizard to 'Cat'
```

You just customize it to suit your need.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. This is very helpful

Comment: I was able to customize according to the need but when file is exported it is generating with default header name "H1". Tried Import-Csv but didn't got expected results for updating the header name. Any suggestions?

Comment: If your input file doesn't have headers at all, you can specify them like this.  `import-csv c:\temp\t.csv -Header Animal,Dog,Cat`.  Remember to mark as answer if this helped you.